# NPM Installs Package Outside Current Directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to install express package using npm from inside /home/iwan/my-project directory:

```
npm install express

express@3.3.7 ../node_modules/express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── fresh@0.2.0
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── debug@0.7.2
├── send@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11)
└── commander@1.2.0 (keypress@0.1.0)
```

The strange thing is npm doesn't install express package in current dir (/home/iwan/my-project/node_modules/express), but in /home/iwan/node_modules/express.

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If the `node_modules` directory doesn't exist in your current directory, NPM will look for it in the higher directories until it finds it.  So, if the parent directory has a `node_modules` directory, NPM will assume that's where it is to install modules.

A quick way around this is to create an empty `node_modules` directory where you want the modules to be placed.

Comment: Actually I came here from google seeking opposite behavior, so I don't have to allways go `cd ..` before installation. Solution was again - just as this answer states - to create `node_modules` in parent directory.

Comment: No this doesn't work. If I install `npm install --save redux` it installed in the folder my command prompt is (by creating `node_modules` folder), and did not checked the `node_modules` folders which was in the parent directory.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan There have been a lot of changes to NPM since this post was written.  It's possible this was one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to install packages with `npm` is to make a `package.json` file. Like this, just put it in the smae directory as your app. A sample `package.json` file could look like this:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.3.5",
    "jade": "*",
    "less-middleware": "*",
    "ejs": "*",
    "mongoose": "3.6.*"
  }
}
```

Take a look at the dependencies list. Just add the module that you want, for example, `underscore`. Just add it to the dependencies dict. Like so:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.3.5",
    "jade": "*",
    "less-middleware": "*",
    "ejs": "*",
    "mongoose": "3.6.*",
    "underscore": "*"   <-------------- Added
  }
}
```

Then head over to your directory and just run `npm install`, and bam! All the packages and their dependencies will be installed for you. It will do all the work, and that means making your `node_modules` folder for you. This is how my app directory looks like:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you. package.json makes app looks more clear & informative.

Comment: Please do not use this example. If you are using * for your packages in production, you will eventually run into breaking changes and spend way too much time fixing them. If you are in active development and want to make sure your packages are all kept up to date, sure, use asterisks, tildes, or carrots, but do not leave them in production.

Comment: I second SgtPooki.  This is a dangerous precedent and will eventually cause production issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a blank package.json file using guidelines from the `https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json` webpage. Then place this in your project folder and type `npm install`.