# npm install directory in Windows is not as I expected

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install npm modules locally but the path where they are installed is weird.

for example, Running 'npm install mocha' in c:\user\administrator\my-project,

I expect it to be installed in c:\user\administrator\my-project\node-modules...

but it is installed in c:\user\administrator\node-modules...

Is there anything I have to configure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18566091/362536

Comment: It was really helpful Brad!