# node_modules missing after local gulp install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I ran into an issue today mid-class. I was showing my class how to install and use gulp.js, so I had to show the process on a projector.

I've installed node.js and gulp.js globally with `npm install -g gulp` and it all works fine.

But when I try to install gulp locally in the project folder I am working on, it looks like gulp is installed, but the node_modules folder is never created.

I tried refreshing, I tried running the command prompt as admin, I've checked for hidden folders, nothing works. --- I even restarted and tried again, cause Windows.

I am working on windows 10.

Transcript of command line output:

```
C:\Xampp\htdocs\test> node -v
v4.2.4

C:\Xampp\htdocs\test> npm -v
2.14.12

C:\Xampp\htdocs\test> gulp -v
[16:40:28] CLI version 3.9.1
[16:40:28] Local version 3.9.1

C:\Xampp\htdocs\test> npm install --save-dev gulp
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
gulp@3.9.1 ..\..\..\node_modules\gulp
├── interpret@1.0.1
├── pretty-hrtime@1.0.3
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── minimist@1.2.0
├── tildify@1.2.0 (os-homedir@1.0.2)
├── semver@4.3.6
├── v8flags@2.0.11 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.1, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0)
├── orchestrator@0.3.8 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── gulp-util@3.0.8 (array-differ@1.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, beeper@1.1.1, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.3, object-assign@3.0.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, dateformat@2.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, fancy-log@1.3.0, vinyl@0.5.3, gulplog@1.0.0, lodash.template@3.6.2, through2@2.0.3, multipipe@0.1.2)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.14 (strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, defaults@1.0.3, graceful-fs@3.0.11, through2@0.6.5, mkdirp@0.5.1, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
└── liftoff@2.3.0 (lodash.isstring@4.0.1, lodash.isplainobject@4.0.6, lodash.mapvalues@4.6.0, extend@3.0.0, rechoir@0.6.2, flagged-respawn@0.3.2, resolve@1.2.0, fined@1.0.2, findup-sync@0.4.3)
```

Note: npm is in my PATH.

Comment: you see those `..\..\..` in the output? you project.json file is two folders up from the folder you are in. So create project.json (npm init) in the place where you are doing npm install

Comment: @vittore I tried these same steps yesterday on a similar setup and it worked fine without package.json, and every single of my students made it work today without ever having made or even knowing what package.json is, so I'm not really sure this is the issue tbh.

Comment: if you don't have that file in current folder it will look for that file in the parent folders. you have one 3 levels up. that's why it installed gulp into node_modules folder 3 levels up.

Comment: Then how did it work for my students on fresh machines with no package.json anywhere in that same tree-system?

Comment: because there were no package.json files anywhere! you have one!

Comment: besides, why you are not starting with `npm init` or cloning some starter repo in the first place?

Comment: Actually, I just checked, and there is no package.json in that folder (3 levels up), but the node_modules is there now... This is really odd. I mean, you're correct, and then not really.

Comment: Your question: because I am teaching my students to create their own boilerplates, in order to understand how they are made and work.

Comment: yeah if you are creating one, you are supposed to start with `npm init`. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566048/npm-installs-package-outside-current-directory

Comment: I'm gonna try the solution with the empty node_modules - it's a hack, but it might work in my case.

Comment: It worked! Cheers for that link :) If you add something like that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either `package.json` or folder named `node_modules` in the current directory. If you are not going to have one, `npm` will look for either one in the parent directories. Check answer to [NPM Installs Package Outside Current Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566048/npm-installs-package-outside-current-directory) for more details.

Also it is advised to start with `npm init` which will create `package.json` for you.